# How to use setCurrentTab method in an activity of tab?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, android-tabhost

I've been having this problem for 1 week.
I have a `MainActivity extends TabActivity` and A, B two activities in each tab.
Now I want to press a button in activity A to set the current page to the tab of activity B
But I can't use `setCurrentTab` method except in `MainActivity`.
How can I make this function work?

`public class MainActivity extends TabActivity`

```
public TabHost tabHost; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Resources res = getResources();
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StartActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("A",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.start))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WeatherActivity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("B",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.weather))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

}
```

```
public class AActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_layout);
        Button b = (button)findViewById(R.id.bt);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
        //Can't work here
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() 
   {
    
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
    {}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try making the following changes :

In Main activity :

1. Make the tabHost variable Static.

   `private static TabHost tabHost`;
2. Add a new function to fetch the current tabhost.

   `public static TabHost getCurrentTabHost(){
   return tabHost;
   }`
3. In AActivity, Use like this :

   `MainActivity.getCurrentTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);`

If required, you can go for a null check.

Comment: Please mark as answer if that works so that it will help others as well.